# How To Access my Sprite properties from outside a function in Phaser3 and Matterjs

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, matter.js

I'm using phaser 3 and Matterjs. I created a function (arrow function) and created a sprite within and it worked fine, but when I set it's velocity within the function it moves a little while and stops, it happens in other instances outside the function (it is a matterjs issue and this might be because I called it in the phaser `create()` function and not `update()` which works, although it works anywhere in arcade physics) and I want to access my Sprite velocity away from the function, I had created it to remove the

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setVelocityX'...)`

and set it's velocity in the `update()` so it wouldn't have to stop on it's way. I would gladly appreciate any working method. Thanks.

**Added Code from the comments:**

```
this.obstacles = this.add.group();
var addObstacle = (x, y) => { 
    // Create a pipe at the position x and y 
    obstacle = this.matter.add.sprite(x, y, 'barrel').setScale(0.2);
    obstacle.setIgnoreGravity(true);
    this.obstacles.add(obstacle);
    obstacle.setVelocityX(-30);
}
var space = 7;
var vary = Phaser.Math.Between(800,1000);
setInterval( _ => {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (i != space && i != space + 1){ 
            addObstacle(screenWidth+400, i * 60 + (vary));
        }
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I'm using mobile and unfortunately can't share code. But this is the current issue this.obstacles = this.add.group()
var addObstacle=(x, y)=>{
    // Create a pipe at the position x and y
    obstacle = this.matter.add.sprite(x, y, 'barrel').setScale(0.2);
    obstacle.setIgnoreGravity(true)
      this.obstacles.add(obstacle);
  obstacle.setVelocityX(-30)}
var space = 7
var vary = Phaser.Math.Between(800,1000)
         setInterval(_ => {
 for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (i != space && i != space + 1) {
    addObstacle(screenWidth+400, i * 60 + (vary))}
     }   },5000)

Comment: Thanks. Can you [edit] that into the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the reason why the `sprite` slows down, is because in `matterjs` the velocity is *"dampened"*, if you don't want that the velocity to be slowed down, just set the friction to `0`, with the function `setFriction` (link [to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Matter.Components.Friction.html))

**like this:**

```
// just needs to be called once, after creating the sprite
sprite.setFriction(0, 0, 0);
```

to get the current velocity, just get it over the `body` property:

**like this:**

```
console.info(sprite.body.velocity.x, sprite.body.velocity.y);
```

**Mini Demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

let text;
let text1, text2;
let rect1, rect2;

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'matter',
        matter: { debug: true }
    },
    scene: { create, update },
    banner: false
}; 

function create ()
{
    text = this.add.text(10, 10, 'Velocity set in "create" function ');
    text1 = this.add.text(10, 30, 'without friction');

    this.matter.world.disableGravity();

    rect1 = this.matter.add.image(10, 70, '_no_texture_');

    rect1.setVelocity(3, 0);
    rect1.setFriction(0, 0, 0);

    text2 = this.add.text(10, 110, 'with friction');
    rect2 = this.matter.add.image(10, 150, '_no_texture_');
    rect2.setVelocity(3, 0);

}

function update(){
    text1.setText(`current velocity without friction ( ${rect1.body.velocity.x.toFixed(2)}, ${rect1.body.velocity.y.toFixed(2)})`);
    text2.setText(`current velocity with friction ( ${rect2.body.velocity.x.toFixed(2)}, ${rect2.body.velocity.y.toFixed(2)})`);
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

**Update, extra demo for comment, question:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

let text;

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'matter',
        matter: { debug: true }
    },
    scene: { create, update },
    banner: false
}; 

function create () {
    text = this.add.text(10, 10, 'obstacels: 0');
    this.matter.world.disableGravity();
    this.obstacles = this.add.group();

    this.time.addEvent({
        delay: 2000,
        loop: true,
        callback: _ => { 
            let newX = Phaser.Math.Between(500, 600);
            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
                let newY = i * 60;
                addObstacle(this, newX,  newY );
            } 
        }
    })
}

function addObstacle(scene, x, y){
    obstacle = scene.matter.add.sprite(x, y, 'barrel')
        .setIgnoreGravity(true) 
        .setVelocityX(-3)   
        .setFriction(0, 0, 0);
        
    scene.obstacles.add(obstacle); 
}

function update(){
  text.setText(`obstacels: ${this.obstacles.children.size}`);

  this.obstacles
    .getChildren()
    .filter(item => item.x < 0)
    .forEach(item => this.obstacles.remove(item))
}


new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: You were right, it works, set the friction to 0. Thanks. Above in a comment I made there was a little code snippet I commented. I want to destroy the obstacles if they go out of screen can't do if(obstacle.x<0){ obstacle.destroy()}

Comment: @AceEnyioko Great that it help. if it answers your question, please accept my answer _(the checkmark)_ . btw.: I updated my answer with an example, with the code from your comments, it shows how you can destroy the obstacles.

Comment: Okay done, I'm very grateful for the answers